# angular 6 обновление vIew

Tags: vkontakte-api, angular2, update, компоненты

есть такой код

```
 userData (id) {
    VK_API.Api.call('users.get', {
      user_ids: id, 
      v:"5.73",
      fields: 'online,photo_200'
    }, (data) => {
      this.currentUser = data.response[0];
      VK_API.Api.call('friends.search', {
        user_id: id,
        count: 5,
        fields: 'photo_100,online',
        v:"5.73"
      }, (friends) => {
        this.currentUser.friends = friends.response.items;
        console.log(this.currentUser);
      });
    });
  }
```

он отрабатывает нормально. в консоль выводит нудные данные.

Почему не обновляется компонент для отображения данных

вот разметка

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="user-logo" *ngIf="currentUser">
    <img class="user-avatar" [src]="currentUser.photo_200"/>
  </div>
  <span>{{ currentUser?.first_name }}</span>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let friend of currentUser.friends | async">
  <span>{{ friend.online }}</span>
</div>
```

если убрать pipe async и оператор ? то ошибки что свойства undefined/
Но  все равно нету обновления данных.
VK_API Это глобальная переменая window экспортится из файла

```
export const VK_API = window.VK;
```

сам скрипт с vk_api подключается в index.html;

```
<script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Потому что вы изменяете свойство  `this.currentUser` вне зоны видимости ангулара. Надо выполнить присваивание в `zone.run()`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819056/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-angular

Comment: так и думал что что то с зонами фигная каката. Не до конца был уверен потому что иногда эти данные появляться потом снова пропадают